# Two almost identical Rails projects, missing gem helper file in one but not the other

Tags: ruby-on-rails, helper, authorize.net

I have two rails projects under the same parent within my home directory with the same environment.  Both use the authorize-net (1.5.2) gem.  I'm using ruby 1.8.7 (2012-02-08 patchlevel 358) [i686-darwin11.4.0], Rails 2.3.14, and rvm 1.14.3 on Mac OS X 10.8.1.  Both have `config.gem 'authorize-net', :lib => 'authorize_net` in their config/environment.rb, both have `helper :authorize_net` at the top of their relevant controllers, both have `helper :all` at the top of their application_controller.rb.  Yet one works fine and the other gets a `MissingSourceFile (Missing helper file helpers/authorize_net_helper.rb)` error.  The helper file is in fact located at `~/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global/gems/authorize-net-1.5.2/lib/app/helpers/authorize_net_helper.rb`

I cannot for the life of me figure out why one works but not the other.  Can anyone point me in the right direction?  How can I figure out what path Rails is using to find this helper in each case?

Comment: Are you using rvm gemsets? If each app has its own gemset you would need to install gems in each one

Comment: I don't believe I'm using gemsets in any way.  There is no .rvmrc in either project's base directory.  The gem is in @global and my GEM_PATH is `/Users/russ/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358:/Users/russ/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.8.7-p358@global`.  The gem only appears in the @global directory.

Answer (score 1):

One thing I've learned over the years of using the StackExchange universe is that when I have a weird problem and don't get an answer within a couple of days, it's something stupid I did that no one else did or probably ever will do.  I imagine this is one of those things, but I'll never know because the problem has gone away and I don't know why.

Realizing that the working project came from authorize.net's example and the non-working one didn't, I discovered that the authorize-net gem had a generator that I had not used.  So I went thru the generator code and realized I was missing an initializer that I was sure I had already created.  This initializer just loads some constants (api_login_id and api_transaction_key) from a YML file and has nothing having to do with paths, but I created it anyway before realizing I had in fact created it before but put it in controllers instead of config/initializers.  Anyway, when I restarted WEBrick, everything worked, no path issues.  Now I have restarted WEBrick MANY times before, including just before posting this question.  But this time the problem went away.

I HATE when this happens.